# Why invalid user input (e.g; city) onSubmit event trigger stops page from rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, state

**I have a weather application with two components where a user type city name etc if it is correct then data is fetched by Api and rendered on the browser but if the user type wrong input like (city name in my case), the whole page stops rendering when I click submit button OR Press enter key(onSubmit).even when the search bar is empty and onClick or onSubmit event trigger, the page gone blank(stops rendering). I want that when the user types the wrong city name or the search bar is empty, the page renders the default weather data or stop fetching the city data on the wrong user input.  Any solution?
App.js Comp**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Maindata from "./Components/Maindata";
import Search from "./Components/Search";

// import Time from "./Components/Time";

function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="mainpage">
      <div className="searchComp">
        <Search {...{ location, setLocation }} />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <Maindata city={location} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Comp 1 Search.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../Componentstyle/search.css";

export default function Search({ setLocation }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");

  const handlesubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLocation(city);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={city}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="nd" type="button" onClick={handlesubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Comp2 Maindata.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../Componentstyle/Main.css";
export default function Maindata({ city = "mansehra" }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const weather = async (city) => {
    const key = "1ab6ef20384db1d7d9d205d609f7eef0";

    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => setData(actualData));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    weather(city);
  }, [city]);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <>
   
    <div className="maindata">
        <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
        <div className="temp">{data.main.temp.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="icon">
          <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
        <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
        <div className="sunrise">
          sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="sunset">
          sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
        </div>
      </div>
    
      
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user does not enter any city before submitting, or if the user enters a city that the API does not recognize, openweathermap will return the following response:

```
{cod: '400', message: 'Nothing to geocode'}
```

Which doesn't have a `weather` property - so although the `data` state exists in the `Maindata` component, doing

```
const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;
```

will fail, throwing a runtime error and preventing rendering.

You need not only

```
if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

but also something like

```
if (!data.weather) {
    return <div>City "{city}" not recognized</div>;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="mainpage">
      <div className="searchComp">
        <Search {...{ location, setLocation }} />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <Maindata city={location} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 function Search({ setLocation }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");

  const handlesubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLocation(city);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={city}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="nd" type="button" onClick={handlesubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
function Maindata({ city = "mansehra" }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const weather = async (city) => {
    const key = "1ab6ef20384db1d7d9d205d609f7eef0";

    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => setData(actualData));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    weather(city);
  }, [city]);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (!data.weather) {
    return <div>City "{city}" not recognized</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <>
   
    <div className="maindata">
        <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
        <div className="temp">{data.main.temp.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="icon">
          <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
        <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
        <div className="sunrise">
          sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="sunset">
          sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
        </div>
      </div>
    
      
    </>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
</script>
```

If you want to preserve the existing rendered map data if the input is invalid, then add another state that keeps track of whether the entered city is valid or not, and use that instead of overwriting the API response state if invalid.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="mainpage">
      <div className="searchComp">
        <Search {...{ location, setLocation }} />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <Maindata city={location} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 function Search({ setLocation }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");

  const handlesubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLocation(city);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={city}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="nd" type="button" onClick={handlesubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
function Maindata({ city = "mansehra" }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [cityValid, setCityValid] = useState(false);
  const weather = async (city) => {
    const key = "1ab6ef20384db1d7d9d205d609f7eef0";

    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => {
        if (actualData.weather) {
          setCityValid(true);
          setData(actualData)
        } else {
          setCityValid(false);
        }
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    weather(city);
  }, [city]);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (!data.weather) {
    return <div>City "{city}" not recognized</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <>
   
    <div className="maindata">
        {!cityValid && <div>City "{city}" not found</div>}
        <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
        <div className="temp">{data.main.temp.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="icon">
          <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like.toFixed()} C</div>
        <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
        <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
        <div className="sunrise">
          sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="sunset">
          sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
        </div>
      </div>
    
      
    </>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
</script>
```

Comment: In addition to your answer. I want to ask that when the city is not found condition becomes true then it just prints the single statement and the remaining previous data disappear..is there any way that if the user value(city name) is wrong then it should stop calling the API Or stop fetching that city data but it should render the last data which was rendering before that input, etc. I hope you understood my question.

Comment: Sure, instead of doing `.then((actualData) => setData(actualData));`, you could first check to see if `actualData` is valid or not. If not, then instead of calling `setData`, you could call another state like `setCityIsValid(false)` - and, when rendering, put an error message if `cityIsValid` is false. When a response comes back successfully, call both `setData` and also `setCityIsValid(true)`